# How to keep keyboard on fragment replace?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments and each has edit text. So what I want to achieve is everytime I create fragment, focus is on edit text and keyboard is shown. Additionally when I replace these fragments, I don't want to hide and show again keyboard, but with my solution this is what is happening now.

I set in manifest this attribute to activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible|stateUnchanged"
```

And each fragment has calls this method in onResume():

```
private void focusOnEditText() {
    mTextInputEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mTextInputEditText.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(mTextInputEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Comment: Are you using viewPager?

Comment: No, simple replacing fragments.

Answer (score -1):

Read the **Documentation** [toggleSoftInput](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html)

```
private void focusOnEditText() {
        mTextInputEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mTextInputEditText.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately now keyboard hides after replacing fragment.

Comment: call this method in onCreateView() of fragment.

Comment: How would I do that if view is created in onCreateView method and I'm refer to EditText. Did you even try your code?